# REALLY important days in history

Tags: knowledge, pattern, number-sequence, sequence, history

@Z. Dailey asks a mathematical puzzle [Important days in history... and to come!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29503/important-days-in-history-and-to-come) with a series of dates in years 1973, 1978, 1983, 1992, 2005.

My puzzle asks the question: What is the previous date in my series? Explain!!

```
.......... .., .....
      June 22, 1973  
.......... .., .....
      June 16, 1978
      June 11, 1983
     March 25, 1992
     April 14, 2005
```

Hint:

> "rudder as a male swan"

Comment: A male swan being a rot13(pbo)

Comment: Apparently [`ebhtu nf n pbo`](https://earlbrussell.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/sayings-that-stuck-2/) is a phrase

Comment: Logic dictates there's a high chance that the year is 1969, the fake moon landing year.

Comment: @Overmind I would question your failed conclusion.

Comment: Nothing failed about it. Also it's valid from a math p.o.v. ;check the MM/DD also.

Comment: @Haobin Is the hint in any way related to the Lufthansa logo?

Comment: I'm assuming it's not January 3, 1972 and April 1, 1975...